# With a custom control that's inside of an ItemTemplate (Repeater), how can I access values from the repeater item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a control, a custom button. This button sits inside of an `<ItemTemplate>`. I'm needing to access the databound values from its parent, the `<ItemTemplate>`.

For example, `<%#Eval("Firstname")%>` can be done within the `<ItemTemplate>`, but not within the control itself, other than exposing values via property tags.

**Note**: I know how to pass these values via property/attribute tags. I can't do that in this case.

I've been playing around with `DataBinder.Eval` but can't seem to access what I need.

Examples of attempts:

```
Dim parent As RepeaterItem = CType(Me.NamingContainer, RepeaterItem)
Dim test = DataBinder.Eval(parent.DataItem, "Firstname")
test = DataBinder.Eval(Me.NamingContainer, "DataItem.Firstname")
test = DataBinder.Eval(DirectCast(DirectCast(parent, RepeaterItem), IDataItemContainer).DataItem, "Firstname")
```

I've never had to do this before, and I also want to strictly do this from code-behind. I can climb the control tree and see that "NamingContainer" is in fact my repeateritem.

Am I missing something? C# or VB.net examples welcome. Will convert it.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, the best way would be to actually parse values via properties.

And I'm not sure you can actually access the DataItem as an object in the post-back scenario you're thinking off.

I think you'll have to actually access the values via the control tree from your custom control, which isn't terrible pretty.

For example. Assume your repeater item has a literal called "yourLiteral" along side your submit button "yourButton".
Then in the code file for "yourButton" and it's submit event, you could do something like:

(C#)

```
  ((Literal) ((RepeaterItem) this.Parent).FindControl("yourLiteral")).Text
```

to get the text value. 
And then substitute for the control types that are relevant to you.